# Create Image from Data URL

Tags: php, gd

What I was hoping to do was use the JavaScript "readAsDataURL" method of the "FileReader" object in order to read file input from a drag and drop.  Then I wanted to use Ajax with a PHP upload file in order to create a file and upload it to an "uploads" folder on the server.

I was wondering if there was a function in GD or something that would allow me to read in a data URL and output a file in which I could move to that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data image URL will usually be base64 encoded, and will then contain a JPG, GIF, or PNG image which you can store.

So a simple `base64_decode()` should do to turn the data into readable form; if you can't know what format the file was in, you may have to write it onto disk to do a [`getimagesize()`](http://www.php.net/getimagesize) on it (unless you can use one of the new "memory" fopen wrappers shown [here](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Could I use a file_put_contents with the result of base64_decode?

Comment: @Camoy sure, it's a normal file after the decoding.